# How should I import tikz-uml package in ShareLatex?

Tags: compiling, sharelatex, tikz-uml

I am using *ShareLatex* (I am new in Latex) and I want to include a UML Class Diagram. I found that tikz-uml package should fit my needs. However, I keep having the following error whenever I try to compile:

```
LateX Error: File 'tikz-uml.sty' not found
```

I tried to compile different examples that I found and all fail in the same line:

```
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
```

As a matter of fact, [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uml-diagrams-with-tikz-uml/ftfzzpmwnjqw#.VvUYNPnhDIU) *Overleaf* tikz-uml example obviously works there, but it doesn't in *ShareLatex*. Do anybody know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In order to use the Tikz-uml package, you will have to upload the package manually. This shouldn't be too difficult. First, you just need to download the latest release of the package from here:

http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en

You will have to extract the downloaded file (twice), then upload the `tikz-uml.sty` file to your ShareLaTeX project. After this, everything should compile perfectly.

Comment: Can you update your answers working for local pc too?

Comment: Or download directly from [Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lebedov/tikzumlx/master/tikz-uml.sty).

Comment: The weird thing is, I clearly remember downloading it from CTAN, not from paristech whatever. But now I can't seem to find a CTAN link.